# Three.js JSON Converter and Loader

Tags: json, 3d, three.js, converters, loader

I tried to get 3D Models from JSON format data, using JSONLoader which loaded in threejs/src/loader dir.

But it failed.

this what I tried on.

1. Resource data format is, obj format.
2. So I converted that obj file to json, using converter that packaged at three.js dir. "convert_obj_three.py"
3. and then tried to load that json file by lower code.

   ```
   var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

   loader.load( './models/museum1.json', museumCallback );

   function museumCallback( geometry,  materials ){
      var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
      model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      model.scale.set (1,1,1);
      model.position.set (0,0,0);
      scene.add( model );            
   }
   ```

I refered the code from "examples/webgl_loader_json_objconverter.html" which inserted the package.

and it failed resulting error message at the console tab.

```
three.js:2993 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefinedsubVectors 
@ three.js:2993computeFaceNormals 
@ three.js:14200parse 
@ three.js:27812(anonymous function) 
@ three.js:27788(anonymous function) 
@ three.js:24521
```

I have a doubt about file format,
so I compared the json file converted and the model which located at "models/teapot-claraio.json".
and I found that these two files is different each other.

and teapot data is loaded by ObjectLoader not JSONLoader.

I have stucked from that time.

I want to loaded 3d model, json file which converted by 'obj2json converter'.

is anyone that have wisdom about this issue?? help me

Comment: I used threejs those revision is 80.